# how to use the color spill node?

Tags: compositing-nodes, color

could anyone share some knowledge on how to use the "color spill" node in Blender's compositor?  Is there any tutorial on this topic...I could not find any.  I need to reduce the background color reflection onto the foreground objects.  Is the color spill node the best tool?
If not, please advise better ways.  Thank you!

Comment: I haven't watched it since I don't need it... so I don't know if it's a good tutorial... but since you couldn't "any", here's one to begin with: [Color Spill, Color Key, Luminance Key... EXPLAINED](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hR9-Xaj7KkU). And since you ask what is the best tool and I don't know exactly what you want to do, maybe this helps: [Chroma Removal in Blender | Keying in Blender | Green Screen Removal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OL9Mcmgwyx8)

Comment: Thank you!  I make room setting furniture renderings.  Sometimes the ambient lighting or wall colors reflect onto the furniture, making the color finish look a bit different.  The tutorials you've recommended are very helpful.